# Using Union in Cognos BI

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I have report that contain 10 queries each query has a filter related to a parameter.

When I union them all and show them in a graph it's not condiring the filtering that been made on the each of the 10 queries it get all.

Anyone have any advise regarding the filters in union is there missing step to include filters in the union?

Many Thanks!!

Comment: Filter for every query should be enough.
You've missed something. Check your filters. Check if your filters aren't optional.

Comment: Just to add to what @AlexeyBaturin said.   Test the individual queries, make sure they're all being filtered correctly.  A union isn't going to prevent filters from being applied.

Comment: For unions to work as you seem to want they have to bombine non-overlapping result sets. If you filter query 1 for a specific value and that same record shows in query 2, the record will still be included when they are unioned together.

Answer (score 0):

actually it's optional but i made it's defualt value to be static so it retrieve nothing the weird part is the chart still able to retrieve all